# Unable to increase timeout or add myself as admin

Tags: drone.io

I'm currently using `DRONE_SERVER=https://cloud.drone.io` as SERVER URL and I'm trying to increase the timeout on my repository but it keeps reverting back to 60 minutes. I've tried adding myself as admin but it doesn't seem to be working. Any idea how I can go about doing this? Any help is appreciated

Comment: https://discourse.drone.io/t/how-to-increase-pipeline-timeout/6120

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to change the timeout for your repo that is enabled on cloud.drone.io? I'm sure that only works for self-hosted drone instances.